# Is there a possibility to make a circle around a node like on the photo?

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees

I would really like to have a circle around the first node of my tree like you can see on the photo. Is there a possibility? I only startet with latex and there is so much new for me... Thank you!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} % Seitenlayout

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} % Zeilenabstand 

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematik
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematik

\usepackage{multirow,array} % Auszahlungsmatrix
\usepackage{arydshln}          % vertikale und horizontale Linien in Tabelle
\dashlinegap=1pt                   % gestrichelte Linie in Tabelle

\usepackage{qtree}          % Spielbaum
\usepackage{tikz}             % Spielbaum
\usetikzlibrary{fit}              % Spielbaum
\usepackage{acronym}     % Spielbaum
\usepackage{anyfontsize} %Spielbaum

\usepackage{float} % Positionierung von Grafiken

%mit Befehl [h] wird versucht, das Objekt dort zu platzieren, wo du angegeben hast
%mit Befehl [t] am oberen Rand der nächsten Seite, auf der es passt
%mit Befehl [b] am unteren Rand analog zu t
%mit Befehl [p] auf einer eigenen Seite

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
 dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}]

\node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,sloped,font=\footnotesize}]

\draw (n11) -- node {passen} (n21);
\draw[dotted] (n11) -- node {drehen} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node {passen} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node {drehen} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
\draw[dotted] (n34) -- node {drehen} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node {passen} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can define an additional style for the first node (or, if it is just one node, you could just apply the settings to the node directly). For example:

```
    ringed dot/.style={circle, fill=black, draw, ultra thick, inner sep=1.95pt, double distance=1.5pt, minimum size=7pt}
```

will produce this result:

[image: ringed dot]

Note that this is an extremely inefficient way to draw the tree and minimally flexible. It would be much simpler to use a dedicated tree-drawing package. TikZ has some of this built-in and an additional `trees` library which extends it. **tikz-qtree** and **forest** are other TikZ-based packages dedicated to trees, which support a more succinct specification of trees. **qtree** supports a similar syntax, but is non-TikZ based. (And there are **pstricks**-type packages for trees, as well.)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}              % Spielbaum

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
    ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
    ringed dot/.style={circle, fill=black, draw, ultra thick, inner sep=1.95pt, double distance=1.5pt, minimum size=7pt}
  ]

  \node[ringed dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

  \node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
  \node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
  \node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
  \node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
  \node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
  \node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,sloped,font=\footnotesize}]

    \draw (n11) -- node {passen} (n21);
    \draw[dotted] (n11) -- node {drehen} (n22);

    \draw (n21) -- node {passen} (n31);
    \draw (n21) -- node {drehen} (n32);
    \draw (n22) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
    \draw (n22) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

    \draw (n32) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
    \draw (n32) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
    \draw[dotted] (n34) -- node {drehen} (n43);
    \draw (n34) -- node {passen} (n44);

    \draw (n43) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
    \draw (n43) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);

  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Alternative Strategies

Here's an illustration of one of the ways I mentioned above to draw the tree more efficiently and flexibly. It is not a question of less typing (though that's relevant), but of ensuring uniform formatting, consistent spacing and ease of tweaking. That is, it should be possible to easily alter the appearance of the tree, to add or remove nodes etc. without needing to perform major surgery on the code.

This solution uses **forest** because I happen to like it.

We begin with the standard three styles for nodes defined above. Since **forest** is based on TikZ, we can use these directly in the tree to style the individual nodes as we wish.

```
\tikzset{%
  dot/.style={fill=black, ring},
  ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
  ringed dot/.style={dot, ultra thick, inner sep=1.95pt, double distance=1.5pt},
}
```

Now for some **forest**-specific styles.

```
\forestset{%
```

The tree involves frequently repeating edge labels, so let's make some styles for those labels to reduce duplication of code.

First, let's specify a special style for formatting all edge labels called `my edge label`. This takes 2 arguments: the location of the label (e.g. `above`) and the content (e.g. `passen`).

```
  my edge label/.style n args=2{
    +edge label/.wrap value={node [sloped, midway, font=\footnotesize, #1] {#2}},
  },
```

Now we'll use this to make two specific styles for edge labels above and below the edge.

```
  edge above/.style={
    my edge label={above}{#1},
  },
  edge below/.style={
    my edge label={below}{#1},
  },
```

Since a given label always occurs above or always occurs below, we can set up styles simply called `passen`, `drehen` etc.

```
  passen/.style={%
    edge above=passen,
  },
```

`drehen` always gets a `dotted` edge.

```
  drehen/.style={%
    edge={dotted},
    edge above=drehen,
  },
```

`kein Schuss` above always matches five-sixths below.

```
  kein schuss/.style={
    edge above=kein Schuss,
    edge below=$\tfrac{5}{6}$,
  },
```

Similarly for Schuss and one-sixth.

```
  schuss/.style={%
    edge above=Schuss,
    edge below=$\tfrac{1}{6}$,
  },
}
```

Now for the tree itself. This is specified in the `forest` environment.

```
\begin{forest}
```

We start by customising the spacing: `l sep+` adds to the distance between the levels. `s sep+` adds to the distance between siblings.

```
  for tree={
    s sep+=25mm,
    l sep+=20mm,
  },
```

Now for a little `stage` magic. Terminal nodes always have a label below and are always a `dot` style. So what we can do is to specify the content of the label in the node itself when writing the tree. Then, before the nodes are typeset, we'll take that content to create a label under the node, deleting the content of the node itself and giving it the `dot` style.

```
  before typesetting nodes={
    where n children=0{
      label/.wrap pgfmath arg={below:$(#1)$}{content()},
      content=,
      dot,
```

We don't do anything to non-terminal nodes: we'll style those directly because there's no (obvious-to-me) pattern.

```
    }{}
  }
```

Now the tree itself using **forest**'s bracket syntax. The root node comes first and uses the `ringed dot` style. It also gets a `pin`.

```
  [, ringed dot, pin=Spieler 1
```

Now for the left branch. The root of this branch gets a `pin`, the `dot` format and we want a `passen` edge label.

```
    [, passen, dot, pin=135:Spieler 2
```

Here's a terminal node. So we put the label into the node itself and the code above will take care of it. Only the edge label needs specifying in addition.

```
      [{0,0}, passen]
```

We continue with the right hand side of the left branch in the same way.

```
      [, drehen, ring
        [{1,-1}, schuss]
        [{-2,2}, kein schuss]
      ]
    ]
```

Now for the main right branch of the tree, starting with a `ring` with edge label `drehen` (and the `dotted` edge style for the line itself).

```
    [, drehen, ring
```

We continue to specify the nodes in this branch in just the same way.

The `schuss` style will place a label above and below the edge, while the content of this node will be used for the label as the node is a terminal one.

```
      [{1,-1}, schuss]
```

This one gets a `pin`, the two labels of the `kein schuss` style and the `dot` format.

```
      [, kein schuss, dot, pin=50:Spieler 2
        [, drehen, ring
          [{1,-1}, schuss]
          [{0,0}, kein schuss]
        ]
        [{0.5,-0.5}, passen]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Having closed out the square brackets which started with the root node, we're ready to end the `forest` environment.

```
\end{forest}
```

Here's the result. Increase `l sep+` and `s sep+` if desired for a more spaced-out tree.

[image: tree with **forest**]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachanpassung
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Silbentrennung bei Sonderzeichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % Direkte Angabe von Umlauten im Dokument
\usepackage{amsmath,forest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{%
  dot/.style={fill=black, ring},
  ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
  ringed dot/.style={dot, ultra thick, inner sep=1.95pt, double distance=1.5pt},
}
\forestset{%
  passen/.style={%
    edge above=passen,
  },
  drehen/.style={%
    edge={dotted},
    edge above=drehen,
  },
  kein schuss/.style={
    edge above=kein Schuss,
    edge below=$\tfrac{5}{6}$,
  },
  schuss/.style={%
    edge above=Schuss,
    edge below=$\tfrac{1}{6}$,
  },
  my edge label/.style n args=2{
    +edge label/.wrap value={node [sloped, midway, font=\footnotesize, #1] {#2}},
  },
  edge above/.style={
    my edge label={above}{#1},
  },
  edge below/.style={
    my edge label={below}{#1},
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    s sep+=25mm,
    l sep+=20mm,
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    where n children=0{
      label/.wrap pgfmath arg={below:$(#1)$}{content()},
      content=,
      dot,
    }{}
  }
  [, ringed dot, pin=Spieler 1
    [, passen, dot, pin=135:Spieler 2
      [{0,0}, passen]
      [, drehen, ring
        [{1,-1}, schuss]
        [{-2,2}, kein schuss]
      ]
    ]
    [, drehen, ring
      [{1,-1}, schuss]
      [, kein schuss, dot, pin=50:Spieler 2
        [, drehen, ring
          [{1,-1}, schuss]
          [{0,0}, kein schuss]
        ]
        [{0.5,-0.5}, passen]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing! (+1) :-)