# Is there a possible way to make these tikz-tree smaller?

Tags: tikz-trees

I do have a little question about my tikz-tree you can see on the photo below. If you polt it on a paper it is quite a bit big and takes almost half of an a4 paper. Now my question: Is there a possibility to make the tree smaller? I tried different things but the problem is the text, which still remain in the same size. The only thing I could change was the text on the lines. There I could fit the font with \footnotesize. But still these size is to big in my opinion. And there are also the numbers which I should make smaller, but I do not really know how to do it. Is there a way to make the whole tree smaller, or do I have to accept it like this? Thank you for your help!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
   ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}]

\node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,sloped,font=\footnotesize}]

\draw (n11) -- node {passen} (n21);
\draw[dotted] (n11) -- node {drehen} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node {passen} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node {drehen} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
\draw[dotted] (n34) -- node {drehen} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node {passen} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `scale=xxx` to any `tikz-picture`. Just make sure to add the scale to any node label as well. As you are using a `scope` here, you will have to add it a third time to the nodes of this scope.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        ,scale=.6
        ,every node/.style={scale=.6}
        ,dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}
        ,ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}
        ]

        \node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

        \node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
        \node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
        \node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
        \node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
        \node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
        \node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,sloped,font=\footnotesize,scale=.6}]

        \draw (n11) -- node {passen} (n21);
        \draw[dotted] (n11) -- node {drehen} (n22);

        \draw (n21) -- node {passen} (n31);
        \draw (n21) -- node {drehen} (n32);
        \draw (n22) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
        \draw (n22) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

        \draw (n32) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
        \draw (n32) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
        \draw[dotted] (n34) -- node {drehen} (n43);
        \draw (n34) -- node {passen} (n44);

        \draw (n43) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
        \draw (n43) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);     
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May you also help me here?^^ http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292017/is-there-a-possibility-to-make-a-circle-around-a-node-like-on-the-photo

Comment: @hpz1719 good luck to you that cfr was quicker than me :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want also smaller text, `\scalebox` seems to be the simplest solution. (Language options commented as meaningless here):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, titlepage]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt},
   ring/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7pt}]

\node[dot,pin=90:{Spieler 1}] (n11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot,pin=135:{Spieler 2}] (n21) at (-4,-1) {};
\node[ring] (n22) at (4,-1) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n31) at (-6,-4) {};
\node[ring] (n32) at (-2,-4) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-1,1)$}] (n33) at (2,-4) {};
\node[dot,pin=50:{Spieler 2}] (n34) at (6,-4) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n41) at (-4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(-2,2)$}] (n42) at (0,-7) {};
\node[ring] (n43) at (4,-7) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0.5,-0.5)$}] (n44) at (8,-7) {};

\node[dot,label=-90:{$(1,-1)$}] (n51) at (2,-10) {};
\node[dot,label=-90:{$(0,0)$}] (n52) at (6,-10) {};

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={above,sloped,font=\footnotesize}]

\draw (n11) -- node {passen} (n21);
\draw[dotted] (n11) -- node {drehen} (n22);

\draw (n21) -- node {passen} (n31);
\draw (n21) -- node {drehen} (n32);
\draw (n22) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n33);
\draw (n22) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n34);

\draw (n32) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n41);
\draw (n32) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n42);
\draw[dotted] (n34) -- node {drehen} (n43);
\draw (n34) -- node {passen} (n44);

\draw (n43) -- node {Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{1}{6}$} (n51);
\draw (n43) -- node {kein Schuss} node[below,sloped]{$\tfrac{5}{6}$} (n52);

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```